# jquery read more link in a div's table cell only

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

so, this is the situation. I've got a table in a div, and this table contains a php recalling a content from MySQL. The fields are like "name", "surname" but also "comment" or "description", that can be quite long, So I'd like to cut them a certain point (like 150 letters) and than add a "read more".
I've tried jquery shorten codes but those only work for the entire div, not for single cells.

Can you guys help me?
Thanks a lot!

M

Comment: show what have you tried and your html .

Comment: "_I've tried jquery shorten codes but those only work for the entire div_" Could you please post that code here?

Comment: php's `substr` http://us2.php.net/substr. apply this when you process the output of description

Answer (score 0):

Try to put 2 things in your long cells (comment & description) :

1. The shortened text you have by using the substr() method
2. The full text

Only show the 1. and on click on your "Read more...", hide the 1. and show the 2.

I wanted to precise my anwser by some HTML / JS code but I'll give you all you give us to get your answer.